# Multiple variables + static value, inserting as one in database

Tags: php, sql, date

In my database, I have the following date field, **2013-12-25**, now I want to fill that with 2 variables and 1 static value something like this:

```
"'2013-".$month."-".$day."'
```

But this won't work. Also I need the "-" spacing the items.

Edit:

this is my complete query

```
    $resultinginsert = mysql_query("INSERT into     content(date,title,details,year,bwID) values ('0004-".$month."-".$day."','".$title."','".$details."','".$year."','".$ID."')");
```

Comment: _But this won't work._ --> Please explain a little more. What does happen? Do you get any errors? Please post them. And please show us some more code.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    "'2013-".$month."-".$day."'"
```

That should work just fine, as long as you have a value for $month and a value for $day and you get your query to the database correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is issue with single and double quotes.  currently you have

```
          "'2013-".$month."-".$day."'
```

try this:

```
          '"2013-".$month."-".$day."'
```